# Example of a Schrödinger operator with compactly supported potential and no zero eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

Is there an example of a Schrödinger operator $-\Delta + V$ in $\mathbb R^3$ with a negative, smooth, compactly supported potential $V$, finitely many negative eigenvalues and no zero eigenvalue?

In general, it seems to be a difficult problem to determine if such an operator with a specific potential has no zero eigenvalue and I just found results for long range potentials, that is, potentials which decay slower than $-\frac{1}{x^2}$. However, I guess it should be quite plausible that such potentials should exist.

Comment: Related?: [Why the statement “there exist at least one bound state for negative/attractive potential” doesn't hold for 3D case?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143630/why-the-statement-there-exist-at-least-one-bound-state-for-negative-attractive)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that there should be at least one negative eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Spherical cavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well#Spherical_cavity), zero eigenvalues occur for certain values of increasing well depth where new eigenvalues come into existence.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia argument could be adapted to to show the same behavior for a (slightly) smoothed Spherical cavity.